# Cost of debenture using IRR method

Tags: finance-mathematics, present-value, debt

**Question:**
A company issued $10000$, $10\%$ debentures of  $\\\$100$ each on 1.4.2020 to be matured on 1.4.2025. Market price of the debenture is $\\\$80$. Tax rate is $35\%$. Then what would be the current cost of existing debt by using IRR or YTM method?

**Context:**
This question is given in my Financial Management Book which I'm unable to solve. 
As per my understanding, since this question is asking to calculate cost of debt using IRR method, I would need to calculate the discounting rate at which NPV would be $0$.

The inflows (initial) for the company would be the initial amount raised i.e. $\\\$80$ per debenture.

The outflows (for 5 years) for the company would be the interest payment $@10\%$ on $\\\$100$ amounting to $\\\$10$ per year.
In addition, the outflows would also include the amount to be repaid at maturity i.e. $\\\$100$. So total outflows will be $\\\$110$.

PV of inflows = $80$.
PV of outflows would be $$  10\sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{1}{(1+r)^i} + \frac{100}{(1+r)^5} .$$

So that would mean I need to calculate $r$ in the following equation:
$$ 80 = 10\sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{1}{(1+r)^i} + \frac{100}{(1+r)^5} .$$

Is it right? But how to continue from there? I'm lost here.